# UIWebview load different files switch langage

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, uiwebview

I have differents embedded HTML files in different languages.
I'd like to load the correct files in a webview based on the current langage.
Is there a way to do that as easily as NSLocalizableString?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use "localized resources", for example

- english version of "index.html" in "en.lproj/index.html",
- french version of "index.html" in "fr.lproj/index.html",

then many resource functions will automatically select the correct version (based on the user's language setting), e.g.:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
```

To create a localized resource "index.html" in Xcode:

- Add the required languages in the "Localizations" section of the "Info" tab of your project (if you have not done that already).
- Select "index.html", and click on "Make Localized" in the File Inspector.
- Select the required languages in the File Inspector.

Now you have one file for each language, for example "index.html (English)" and "index.html (French)", which are copied to the appropriate folder when you install the app.

Comment: waouh I can even do that for my images that's really cool! great feature I didn't know

Comment: @Mathieu: You might want to have a look at the "Bundle Programming Guide" and the "Resource Programming Guide" from Apple, where this concept is also explained.

Answer (score 0):

If for current language you mean the phone language you could achieve your goal doing this :

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

the method return a two letter string representing the current language, IT(Italian),EN(English),DE(German) etc. So based on the language you should be able to load the corresponding HTML file.