# Using a different database depending on locale in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql, database, localization

In my current project, the iOS application is to use a different database depending on location. The database is in raw SQL, so each database is represented as a database file, and is queried by creating a connection to the database.

I am aware that this could be implemented using the *.lproj folders, and if so, I am interested in the most advised way of loading, and using, the respective database.

When searching the web, I have considered using a DatabaseHelper class, which manages the databases and includes an instance of NSLocale, which is set using

```
- (void) initWithLocale {
  [super init];
  locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
}
```

could this be used to determine which database to load, or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12919534/1187415) explains the process for a localized "index.html" file, it should be easy to modify that for a localized "db.sqlite" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using localizations, I think which is very simple.

On your localizations `.strings` files. Add a key and value for each database file names.

Eg: for **English**

```
"my db" = "englishdb.sqlite";
```

for **Spanish**

```
"my db" = "spanishdb.sqlite";
```

Wherever you are accessing the database name use:

```
NSString *dbName = NSLocalizedString(@"my db", @"");
```

---

If you are using the `[NSLocale currentLocale];` the best way is to add the `database names as value` and `locale names as key` of a `plist` and take the database name from that plist according to the locale.

Comment: Better would be to go for localization strings cuz there is Base localization where you can specify default filename. If you go for locale then you have to make sure you have database file for each locale ;-)

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, you are correct. If the locale is not in plist, it'll cause huge damage to your logic. So better go for Localization